# When does the accept() function creates a new socket?

Tags: c, sockets

Does the `accept()` function creates a new socket once a SYN packet is received or when the 3-way handshake is completed? does this depends on the operating system used?

Comment: Related: [How TCP backlog works in Linux](https://veithen.io/2014/01/01/how-tcp-backlog-works-in-linux.html)

Comment: Neither. It creates a socket when it finds a completed connection on the backlog queue, and returns it.

Comment: Or as I like to explain it. `listen` is what tells the operating system to start accepting TCP connections. It's entirely possible that the TCP handshake is fully completed before `accept` has been called. Otherwise, `accept` waits for a completed connection if one isn't already available. Then returns a socket (file handle) to the user-mode application.